# GlobalFilter items from PrimeNG datatable change rowIndex too

Tags: arrays, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

Overflow Community, I want some help on Angular PrimeNG data-table. 
Currently what is happening is `row-index` is assigned against each row and works fine but when I apply search filter on row-index got updated again from 0.

What I want is to attain the row number against each row even after I search.
You can see in the attached Screenshots for a better understanding. Pre-sales data has index 5 and after search it is updated to 0. All I want is to not update the index after search.

[image]
[image]